# How to deploy a Keras CNN Model to webservice?

Tags: python, tensorflow, request, keras, google-cloud-ml

I am currently in the process of trying to deploy a Keras Convolutional Neural Network for a webservice.

I had tried converting my saved keras hdf5 model to a tensorflow.js model and deploying that but it slowed down the client-side app as the model is relatively robust and thus, takes a large amount of space in the client memory.

Thus, I am trying to figure out a way to deploy the model in the cloud and make predictions through a request from the web-app with an image, and then receive a response which holds the prediction tensor. I know that gcloud may have some similar abilities or feature but I am unsure of how to get started.

Essentially, I am asking if there is any service that will allow me to deploy a pre-trained and saved convolutional neural network model to which I can send images in a request and use the model to return a predicted tensor?

Comment: We normally use Flask to build api for such model. Say you have a large model which needs to be loaded in a different server, by building a simple REST api in flask, the client side app can make request with a image, then the api will send back the response. Model related stuffs happen in the Flask backend.

Answer (score 2):

You can export a trained Keras model and serve it with [TensorFlow Serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/). TF Serving allows to host models and call them via either gRPC or REST requests. You could deploy a flask app with an endpoint that accepts an image, wraps it as a payload and calls your model via the `requests` module.

Your code to export the model as a servable would look like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# The export path contains the name and the version of the model
model = keras.models.load_model('./mymodel.h5')

# Feth the Keras session and save the model
with keras.backend.get_session() as sess:
    tf.saved_model.simple_save(
        sess,
        export_dir,
        inputs={'images': model.input},
        outputs={t.name:t for t in model.outputs})
```

This will store the files necessary for TF Serving. From this directory, you can host the model as follows:

```
tensorflow_model_server --model_base_path=$(pwd) --rest_api_port=9000 --model_name=MyModel
```

Your request would then look like this:

```
requests.post('http://ip:9000/v1/models/MyModel:predict', json=payload)
```

Where `payload` is a dictionary that contains your request image.

Comment: You should use tf.saved_model.simple_save():

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about it, I'll check it out and update my answer. Thanks.

Comment: When I am trying to export the model as servable I am getting an error: "RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session." How do I remedy this?

Comment: Are you running your code in a notebook? You can check [here](https://blog.ml6.eu/training-and-serving-ml-models-with-tf-keras-3d29b41e066c) for some more example code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a click-to-deploy solution for serving your model on Google Cloud, consider using [Cloud ML Engine's Online Prediction service](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/online-predict). First, follow the instructions in @sdcbr's response to export your `SavedModel`. Copy the model to GCS then you simply create a model and a version:

```
gcloud ml-engine models create "my_image_model"
gcloud ml-engine versions create "v1"\
    --model "my_image_model" --origin $DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE
```

Or, even easier, use Cloud Console to do the above with a few clicks!

You will get a serverless REST endpoint that includes authentication and authorization, autoscaling (including scale to zero) as well as logging and monitoring, without having to write or maintain a line of code.

Comment: Note that for image models we are introducing new hardware. To gain access to it, please email cloudml-feedback@google.com

Comment: I've got my model with the .pb file and related variables file saved on google cloud storage and linked to a model in the ml engine. How do I go about finding the URL for a post request or actually using the model for prediction?

Comment: You may find it easiest to use a client library as described in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/online-predict#requesting_predictions), particularly to get auth tokens. The direct answer is https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/project/MYPROJECT/models/MY_MODEL:predict